# method processTickets in class BlancovichProject3 cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

I am getting an error that looks like this:

```
1 error found:
    File: C:\Users\Josh\Documents\java\BlancovichProject3.java  [line: 18]
    Error: method processTickets in class BlancovichProject3 cannot 
           be applied to given types;
    required: java.lang.String,java.lang.String
    found: no arguments
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I am getting the error in the third method where it processes tickets.
The code that has the problem is here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class BlancovichProject3
{
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        //methods
        String inputFileName=getInputFileName();
        String outputFileName=getOutputFileName();
        processTickets();
    }

    //getting the input file name
    public static String getInputFileName()
    {
        String inputFileName;
        System.out.println("what is the name of the input file ?");
        inputFileName=keyboard.nextLine();
        return inputFileName;
    }

    //getting the output file name
    public static String getOutputFileName()
    {
        String outputFileName;
        System.out.println("What would you like to save this file to?");
        outputFileName=keyboard.nextLine();
        return outputFileName;
    }

    //    processing tickets
    public static void processTickets(String inputFileName, String outputFileName)throws IOException
    {
        PrintWriter outputFile=new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
        int amount;
        // the tickets prices
        int tprice1=0;
        int tprice2=0;
        int tprice3=0;
        String ticket1=null;
        String ticket2=null;
        String ticket3=null;
        // the total price
        double price=0;
        // customers name
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        // type of ticket
        String seat;
        //processing tickets
        File file = new File(inputFileName);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        ticket1=inputFile.next();
        tprice1=inputFile.nextInt();
        ticket2=inputFile.next();
        tprice2=inputFile.nextInt();
        ticket3=inputFile.next();
        tprice3=inputFile.nextInt();
        outputFile.println(ticket1 + " "+"$" + tprice1);
        outputFile.println(ticket2 + " "+"$" + tprice2);
        outputFile.println(ticket3 + " "+"$" + tprice3);
        outputFile.println();
        // getting customer name,number of tickets, type of ticket
        while (inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            firstName = inputFile.next();
            lastName = inputFile.next();
            amount = inputFile.nextInt();
            seat = inputFile.next();
            // doing math for final billing.
            if(seat.equals(ticket1))
                price = tprice1*amount;
            else if (seat.equals(ticket2))
                price = tprice2*amount;
            else if (seat.equals(ticket3))
                price = tprice3*amount;
            // printing in format to file
            //outputFile.printf("%-10s%-10s$%,.2f\n", firstName, lastName,price);
            outputFile.printf("%-10s%-10s$%,.2f\n", firstName, lastName, price);
            outputFile.println();
        }
        inputFile.close();
        outputFile.close();
    }
}
```

---

Again thank you for any help.

Comment: How many arguments does `processTickets` take & how many are you passing in?

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the mismatch that the compiler error message has told you about, by providing the 2 arguments that `processTickets` requires.  You have them available (`inputFileName` and `outputFileName`) in the 2 lines that precede the call to `processTickets`.

Comment: Thanks got that fixed and is working now.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling processTickets() without arguments